# Xpath - multiple nested divs with tables holding text value

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

I encountered complicated html structure on website from which i want to extract text information.

Website has following structure:

```
<ul class = "listing_pages">
    <li id = "list_1" style = ""></li>
    <li id = "list_2" style = ""></li>
    <li id = "list_3" style = ""></li>
    <li id = "list_4" style = ""></li>
    <li id = "list_5" style = ""></li>
    <li id = "list_6" style = ""></li>
    <li id = "list_7" style = ""></li>
    <li id = "list_8" style = ""></li>
    <li id = "list_9" style = ""></li>
</ul>
```

Each `id="list_*"` unfolds into

```
<li id="list_1">
<div class="description_block">
<table valign="top">
<tbody>
<tr valign="top">
<td width="400px">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width:350px">
<div></div>
<table></table>
<table cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td height="15px">
<h2>
<a class="product_title" title="PRODUCT_NAME" href="http://example.com">PRODUCT_NAME</a>
```

Its nightmarish structure! And its repeated for eatch `list_*`

Relative Xpath for following is

`/div[9]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/h2/a`

Which fails.

Few things i tried, with limited success are,

`response.xpath('//*[@id="one"]//table//tr//h2//a[position()]//text()').extract()`

This extracts all `/h2/a` from page, not from single `list_*`

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="list_1"]//table//tr//h2//a//text()').extract()
```

This extracts text correctly but only from first `list_1` div. I can increment it with `extract()[++i]`, but that is not optimal solution and i think there are definitely better ways to do it.

What i want to accomplish is:

Extract text (PRODUCT_NAME) from each list_* in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try `css` selector like: `response.css('li[id*="list_"] a.product_title::text').extract()`?
Or xpath `response.xpath('//li[contains(@id, "list_")]//a[contains(@class, "product_title")]/text()')`?

UPD: For iteration:

```
for item in response.css('li[id*="list_"]'):
    print item.css('a.product_title::text').get()
```

or

```
for item in response.xpath('//li[contains(@id, "list_")]'):
    print item.xpath('.//a[contains(@class, "product_title")]/text()').get()
```

Comment: Same as above comment. Works, but extracts all the //a from all the list_*. How can i make it to iterate through each and single list_*. Incrementing it is a solution, but both not elegant and also list_[number] is not stable for each page.

Comment: I updated post with iterative variant. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: Thanks! Solution for my code was to get rid of for loop and connect both of your suggested paths in one to avoid repetition of same item. It was correct answer nevertheless. My Xpath goes like this ````response.xpath('//li[contains(@id, "list_")]//a[contains(@class, "product_title")]/text()').extract_first()````

Answer (score 0):

Why not to find all links and extract text from the

```
response.xpath('//a[@class="product_title"]/text()').extract()
```

Comment: That does it, but in the same way as my proposed solution. It grabs all //a from all list_*. I want scrapy to go through list_1 grab a[1], then to list_2, grab a[2]

Comment: @Alex16237 So, from every `n`-th list you want to get `n`-th link?